# Lightweight version of excel countifs formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

I'm adding the following formula to a table through VBA:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "= ""Red: "" & COUNTIFS([RAG],""Red"",[Supply Order Number],[@[Demand Order Number]]) 
        & "", Amber: "" & COUNTIFS([RAG],""Amber"",[Supply Order Number],[@[Demand Order Number]]) 
        & "", Green: "" & COUNTIFS([RAG],""Green"",[Supply Order Number],[@[Demand Order Number]])"
```

It checks a status column for orders that are coded Red, Amber or Green. If the supply and demand order match it tallies up the number of Green, Amber and Red entries for each demand order. Unfortunately this all but cripples the spreadsheet and so I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to add this formula to the table and reduce the memory required.

Comment: What is your issue here? The `CountIf` function is exactly for that use case: Count all cells that meet a certain criteria. So this is probably the fastest way you got. Also I see no issue here. How many data rows do you have?

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ Thanks for your reply. There are up to 20,000 rows of data. I wondered it it would be possible to add the formula to a loop and calculate the cells one by one and if that would reduce the likelihood of the sheet crashing. Not necessarily looking for a faster solution, perhaps just a less memory intense one.

Comment: So is there an error? If so please tell which? The sheet should be able to handle this for this one formula. How often do you use this formula? Do you have an other formulas that put a heavy load? • I don't see how this has something to do with memory? Why do you assume such an issue? • Please be more precise about what your actual problem is.